# Prevent Activity from destroying when Intent launched via Action view or send

Tags: android-intent

This happens in devices from version Jelly Bean.I have an Activity where, suppose i launch  Play store via intent ACTION_VIEW, the activity's onDestroy  is called once play store is loaded ,and returning back, the webview reloads as on onCreate is called.I need to prevent reloading of webview.Before that, how to prevent activity from being destroyed. Surprisingly  this doesn't happen in version 4 and below.

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.myapp"));
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(in);
```

Comment: Is setting the flag (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) needed here? Any particular purpose for this?

Comment: commenting  (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) also produce the same result

Comment: is this anything to do with android:configChanges in manifest file for this activity .I have not set any configChanges .I am testing in the same portrait mode.

Comment: If your activity supports both orientation, then it will matter as on orientation change activity is recreated.

Comment: adding android:configChanges="orientation" also produce the same result .hence i am testing without changing the orientation, i suppose adding configChanges to manifest shall have no effect.